# 'No such module' using modular architecture with CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm applying Modular Architecture described in this [text](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/a-modular-architecture-in-swift-aafd9026aa99). I've created one child project for each module of my system. On my Presentation child project I'm using RxSwift, so in my Podfile what I have is:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

workspace 'ios-swift-template'

target 'Presentation' do 
  project 'ios-swift-template/Modules/Presentation/Presentation.project'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
end

target 'Networking' do 
  project 'ios-swift-template/Modules/Networking/Networking.project'
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
end

target 'ios-swift-template' do
end
```

Even so, when I try to compile the the project it says that the BaseViewController (a class inside the Presentation Module) cannot find RxSwift. If I try to build or run only the Presentation Module it runs without errors.

[image]

In my project Build Phases I have all the module frameworks being copied to the project:

[image]

Why isn't the RxSwift not being found during the build time?

Comment: Did you run `pod install` ?

Comment: Yes. As I said. If I run only the Presentation module it compiles without any erros, the RxSwift is found and everything works fine, the problem is when I try to compile the main target. The iOS-swift-template target, that contains all the app modules.

Answer (score 0):

Add pod 'RxSwift' also under target 'ios-swift-template' and also any other pod that the main target could refer to, directly or indirectly, and re-run pod-install. The main target doesn't see the pods contained in internal framework. Take a read on this for more explanation:

https://medium.com/@akfreas/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-your-internal-ios-frameworks-192aa472f64b

If you take a deeper look in "Modular Architecture in iOS" article, he's doing quite the same, obwohl he first defines the RxSwift pod with a "core_pods" alias and then including it in the framework target but also in the "application_pods" further included in the application target. So, you see, the application target must also to install the RxSwift pod.

Comment: I already tried adding the `RxSwift` pod at the common pods. The version on my question was the current version, a different attempt to fix the problem. With the pod included in the common pods the problem persists.